# Iterating through events

Tags: web3js, events

I have events (fired some time ago by the contract) containing numbers.
I need to load them all, and then to draw a chart.

What I do:

```
contract.getInitBlock(function(error, value)
{
    var init_block = value.toNumber();
    var prevTransactions = contract.updateHistory({_from: web3.eth.coinbase}, 
        {fromBlock: init_block, toBlock: 'latest'}); 
    prevTransactions.watch(function(err, result) 
    {
        if(err) 
        {
            return;
        }

        add_info_to_history(result);

    });
});

window.setTimeout(function() 
{
    chart();
}, 3000);
```

But this is a bad style.

Question: how can I find out that I got ALL events iterated and it is time to draw chart?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using .watch() which listens for new events being fired, you can use .get() to retrieve all past events fired.

Something like:

```
contract.getInitBlock(function(error, value)
{
    var init_block = value.toNumber();
    var events = contract.[[EVENT_NAME]]({[[INDEX_NAME]]:[[INDEX_VALUE]]},{fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
    events.get(function(err, result) 
    {
        console.log("Events that matched: ",result);
        // Iterate through events or do whatever you want with the resulting array
    });
});
```

[[EVENT_NAME]] should be the name of the event

[[INDEX_NAME]] and [[INDEX_VALUE]] should be used if you want to filter the events by some idex you used when you fired them.